# New to JavaScript, jQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-events

I've figured out how to use a jQuery drag-drop sortable ui. I've also figured out how to populate the jQuery list with time data from my table. But... I'm up against another brick wall.

Following is the script for test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// include database connection file, if connection doesn't work the include file will throw an error message
include '../schedule/include/db_connect.php';

    $date1 = "10/01/2012";
        echo $date1;
       
// strtotime() will convert nearly any date format into a timestamp which can be used to build a date with the date() function.
$timestamp = strtotime($date1);
$start_date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);

$result="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(List_Dates.DB_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') as newdate, DATE_FORMAT(List_Time.TFM_Time,'%h:%i %p') as newtime
FROM List_Dates, List_Time
WHERE DATE(DATE_FORMAT(List_Dates.DB_Date,'%Y-%m-%d')) LIKE '" . $start_date . "%'
ORDER BY List_Time.TFM_Time";

$answer = mysql_query($result);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../schedule/include/formats.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery/themes/custom-theme/jquery.ui.all.css">
        <script src="../jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

        <script src="../jquery/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery/ui/jquery.ui.selectable.js"></script>
        <style>
        #sortable1, #sortable2 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 2.5em; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
        #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
        </style>
        <script>
        $(function() {
                $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
                        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
                }).disableSelection();
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<ul name="timelist" id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($answer))
{
        echo "<li class='ui-state-default'>". $row['newtime'] ."</li>";
}
?>
</ul>

<ul name="blocklist" id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <li id="blocked" type="date" class="ui-state-highlight"></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I mentioned earlier, the script is successfully populating a sortable drag-drop list with times from my database. I can drag and drop one time from the left side timelist to the right side blocklist. Now I need to extract an array from the blocklist. I found the following:

```
<script>
$('ul#myList li').each(function(){
var number = $(this).find('span:first-child').text();
var fruit = $(this).find('span:first-last').text();
});
</script>
```

For my application it makes sense to change the syntax as follows:

```
<script>
$('ul#sortable2 li').each(function(){
var btime = $(this).find('span:first-child').text();
});
</script>
```

But... I can't figure out how to successfully use it and echo the results. Everything I've tried results in failure. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jQuery UI documentation there is a method called toArray which you can call on your sortable element to get, well, an array.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-toArray